# Why am I getting a 401 when trying to connect to an external API in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openweathermap

I'm trying to make a call to the Open Weather Map API using a a [gem](https://github.com/coderhs/ruby_open_weather_map) by the same name. I'm trying to fetch the current forecast in a city. I've looked at their FAQ but can't work it out. When I try and load http://localhost:3000/forecasts/berlin_weather this is returned: `Berlin forecast: {"cod"=>401, "message"=>"Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}` Which suggests it is connecting, but not sure why I am not getting the response I expected. Here is my code.

services/open_weather_api.rb

```
class OpenWeatherApi
  require 'open_weather'

  def initialize(city, appid = "blahblahblah", units = "metric")
    @options = { city: city, units: units, APPID: appid }
  end

  def berlin_forecast
    OpenWeather::Forecast.city(@options)
  end
end
```

forecasts_controller.rb

```
class ForecastsController < ApplicationController

  def berlin_weather
    @forecast = OpenWeatherApi.new("Berlin").berlin_forecast
  end
end
```

berlin_weather.html.erb

```
<p>Berlin forecast: <%= @forecast %></p>
```

Comment: Are setting the API key, like the error message is suggesting?

Comment: @bo-oz Yes, API key is set in my service class. Will add it to encrypted credentials once I get it working.

Comment: I would open an issue with the gem author, probably something has changed in the API. Check out Open Weathers API doc and compare it to gem's functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Before making a request to API, you should to register and get API KEY from them!
Follow the instruction here!
https://openweathermap.org/appid

Then when they will provide a key for you, you can use this key in your request!

```
def initialize(city, appid = "API KEY WHAT THEY WILL GIVE YOU", units="metric")
    @options = { city: city, units: units, APPID: appid }      
end
```

Comment: Yes, I have done this already. It is not in my example code because I don't want everyone to know my key, so I replaced it with "blahblahblah"

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'open_weather'

# get current weather by city name
OpenWeather::Current.city("Cochin, IN", options)
```

You need to provide country code as well.
Code sample taken from open_weather ruby wrapper github page.

### Edit

https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily/?appid=b6907d289e10d714blah&id=1298824&units=metric

I believe the api key that send to your mail during registration was wrong. You have to inspect the network call in openweathermap.org to get the real api key

[image]